# How to show shuffling of images on webview like flash movies in ios?

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, uiimage

What I exactly want is that I have an HTML code having swf file but as ios doesn't support flash. so i called api to get images from server. Now i want to write a code in html so that i can show shuffling images on webview. Is it possible?

Comment: you mean something like this http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ or this :http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/roundrr/

Comment: do u have the html mark up and javascript?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can create a script and embed it into an HTML and call the function in `<body onload=>` and pass it to the webView
something like this

```
<body onload="startTime();">
<script>
var imgArray = new Array("images/1.png","images/2.png","images/3.png");
var imgCount = 0;
function startTime() {
if(imgCount == imgArray.length) {
imgCount = 0;
}
document.getElementById("imgId").src = imgArray[imgCount];
imgCount++;
setTimeout("startTime()", 5000);
}
</script>
```

have a look at this [Link](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/131227/changing-images-in-html) if it helps

Comment: If an answer helps you, mark it as correct.